# EF won't migrate after database restore

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm going crazy... I've been trying to write integration tests that restore a database. In the process of writing these tests, I've been playing with my SQL Server User Settings. In the end, I pulled the plug on this. But now I am stuck in a situation where my database is no longer being Migrated...

I keep getting errors like `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.SomeObjectThatWasCreated2MigrationsAgo'`.

The migrations in the table `__Migrations` are way behind and they just won't get updated. No error messages, just a blaring 'nope, can't find that table'

Please help.. What settings do I need in SQL Server to allow Migrations again?

I have set permissions `db_datareader`, `db_datawriter`, `db_ddladmin` and even `db_owner`, but my IIS_APPPOOL user just won't initiate a Migration

**Edit**

No code changes whatsoever since the last migration. No local changes. Nothing. When I restore a backup of the database this happens. Then, once this state is reached, deleting the database didn't even help anymore, no new DB was generated.

D'you know what finally fixed it, after hours of messing about? Recompiling. That's right, after restoring a database I have to *recompile* my application. Even though I have made no changes. Even though I had compiled the application before I restored the database. And regardless of the fact that during the development of the last migration, I used that exact database to add another layer.

I checked and I can reproduce this every time. Restore the database and don't recompile: No migration executed. Restore database and recompile: Migration is executed.

Mind you, I have *no code changes* what-so-ever...

So now my question is: Why? I'm baffled.

**Edit 2**

Coming back to this after a while. I still have this problem. If I add a new Migration, and then run my application, it migrates *fine*.

But, if I then restore my database to before the migration, and run my application, it *doesn't* migrate. I have to re-compile my application. Even worse, should I ever have to restore my database in production, then I would have to re-release my entire application.

If I DROP my entire database, I also have to recompile.

**In reply to questions**

This is an automatic migration. I have `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false`

DatabaseInitializer:

```
    Database.SetInitializer(
            new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, 
                    MyNameSpace.Configuration>());
```

**Edit 4**
I discovered that I need to do an ApplicationPool restart. 
This is the scenario:

1. Build applications
2. Restore database
3. Migrations not applied. Application crashes due to missing tables

This is the workaround:

1. Build applications
2. Restore database
3. Restart ApplicationPool
4. Migrations are applied

It seems something is stored in memory that says "Yep, we've done all migrations. Nosirree, nothing to do here."

It's probably a performance optimization, but it is really inconvenient because I can't reset the AppPool on our production environment. If anyone knows how I can switch this behavior off, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: That sounds more like messed up migrations than security. I would start by seeing what EF is trying to do by generating a script `update-database -Script`. Another thing you could do is point your connect string at a new database and make sure that works.

Comment: Are we talking about automatic or manual migrations? What database initializer is configured?

Comment: @grek40, added answers to your questions above.

Comment: Sorry, I'm always working with manual migrations, so I don't know enough about the internals and gotchas of automatic migrations. I avoid them because I don't fully trust EF scaffolding.

Comment: Actually the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer and automatic/manual migrations are different things. The initializer just applies the pending migrations, regardless of them being automatic/manual. So to make the case clear, do you have `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;` inside your `MyNameSpace.Configuration` class constructor?

Comment: @IvanStoev, I have AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;. I don't want migrations to be created without me saying so explicitly. However, in the past I did not have this yet. This caused me some grief. After which I enabled it. Can it still be bugging me from the past?

Comment: I'm not saying anything for now, just trying to reproduce the issue. And I can't.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you for trying.

Comment: You are welcome. One last question - where is `Database.SetInitializer(…)` line located in your code? Mine is inside my `DbContext` constructor. Also what type of application (my test is on ConsoleApp) and EF6 version (mine is 6.2) are we talking about? Actually it would be nice if you can setup small repo which can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @IvanStoev Database.SetInitializer is located outside my DbContext, in my IoC bootstrapper. I don't have a small testcase right now, will see if I can create one.

Comment: try the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823997/is-it-possible-to-make-migrations-simplified/53830727#53830727

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this problem. So If I have restored the database,I used to remove the entry of the migration(s) and then when I do the ef update command it will successfully run the migration as it will assume that it was never run before.

Also I never use migrations to update production database. For that, I was always generating the incremental scripts and then running those. Basically once I am done with the first production roll-out, I will use backup for restoring databases, and will also generate scripts for the stable version of the database, and version those somewhere (DB_SQl1.0.sql) and then create the incremental scripts. If creating the script is a problem, you can generate those directly from code-base for each of the migrations individually.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#generate-sql-scripts

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem twice. I couldn't find the solution either but this was the workaround I used:

1. Backup your database
2. Create another database
3. Change your connection string to this new database
4. Update migrations to the new database

```
dotnet ef database update
```

5. Delete all records of your migration table:

```
delete from currentDB..[__EFMigrationsHistory]
```

6. Copy all migrations from the new database:

```
insert into currentDB..[__EFMigrationsHistory] 
select * from newDatabase..[__EFMigrationsHistory]
```