# is it possible to make migrations simplified ?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core

During development we did such things as create table, drop index, etc in our migrations (let say we have over hundreds migrations file).
Now I want to deploy on production server, could I create simplified migration like in 1 file to summary all of the changes on my development ?

to clarify I give example :
migrations 1 - create table student
migrations 2 - rename student_name to student_full_name
migrations 3 - rename address to student_address

now I want to have a better migration file like when we create student table we already have correct field name (student with field student_full_name and student_address)

how to do that in dotnet ef core 2.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following  ( after backing up )
take note of the version number in the migrations table in the production database
delete all the migrations older than that from the code
set the connection string to the production database
add a migration.